# Switching from MySQL ADO.NET libraries to MySQL connector issue

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I have switched my C# project from MySQL ADO.NET libraries to MySQL connector since there was a bug in MySQL libraries.

Previous Question related to the aforementioned issue: [StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52377797/9589180)

I have used [MySql Connector](https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/) documentation as the reference for switching libraries.

Following the change of the libraries, there were some new errors triggered for the MySQL keywords in the existing project.

1) `MySqlConnection` in private `MySqlConnection connection;` line.

> Error: Represents an open connection to a MySQL Server database. This
>   class cannot be inherited. The type 'MySqlConnection' exists in both
>   'MySql.Data' and 'MySqlConnector'.

2) `MySqlException` in  `catch (MySqlException ex)` line.

> Error: The Exception is thrown when MySQL returns an error. This class
>   cannot be inherited. The type 'MySqlException' exists in both
>   'MySql.Data' and 'MySqlConnector'.

3) `MySqlCommand` in `MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();` line.

> Error: Represents a SQL Statement to execute against a MySQL database.
>   This class cannot be inherited. The type 'MySqlCommand' exists in both
>   'MySql.Data' and 'MySqlConnector'.

4)  `MySqlDbType` in `cmd.Parameters.Add("?jobNo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (values[0]);` line.

> Error: Specifies MySQL specific data type of a field, property, for
>   use in a MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter. The type
>   'MySqlDbType' exists in both 'MySql.Data' and 'MySqlConnector'.

Any suggestions on how to mitigate the above errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary error is:

> The type 'MySqlConnection' exists in both 'MySql.Data' and 'MySqlConnector'.

It appears that your project is referencing both `MySql.Data.dll` and `MySqlConnector`. Uninstall the `MySql.Data` package using NuGet Package Manager, and make sure the `MySql.Data.dll` reference is removed from your csproj, `packages.config` etc.

(In advanced scenarios, you can use an [extern alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias) to reference both libraries, but I would strongly discourage it: it can cause two connection pools to be created, two cleanup threads to be started, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

*The type 'MySqlConnection' exists in both 'MySql.Data' and 'MySqlConnector'* indicates the type has present in both assemblies, which causing ambiguous reference. Normally you can simply remove `MySql.Data.dll` references using NuGet package manager with `Uninstall-Package MySql.Data` command (and removing all possible traces of that assembly) then reference issue should be resolved, but in certain conditions you can do steps below:

1. Go to reference properties and set alias `MySqlConnector` for assembly before all `using` statements, e.g. `extern alias MySqlConnectorAlias;`.
2. Use reference from the alias on step (1), e.g. `MySqlConnectorAlias::MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection`.
3. (For .NET Core only) Before using steps (1) and (2), edit the .csproj file which contains `ChangeAliasesOfStrongNameAssemblies` like this:

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

      <!-- other stuff -->

      <Target Name="ChangeAliasesOfStrongNameAssemblies" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
          <ItemGroup>
              <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'MySqlConnector'">
                  <Aliases>MySqlConnectorAlias</Aliases>
              </ReferencePath>
          </ItemGroup>
     </Target>

     <!-- other stuff -->

   </Project>
   ```