# The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method [MySQL connector]

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

This question is related 2 of my previous questions which have been posted on StackOverflow in last few days.

1st Question which was regarding a MySqlClient EndOfStreamException.

[1st Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52377797/9589180)

The answer for the 1st question leads me to Switch libraries from MySQL ADO.NET  to MySQL connector.

I had some issues with some MySQL keywords since moving from MySQL ADO.NET  to MySQL connector. I got the answer to that question as well.

[2nd Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52416026/9589180)

Now the program is running without any errors. But unfortunately, there is a catch since the data is not written to the database whatsoever.

With the intent of finding a solution to this issue I tried to add **"await"** keyword to ExecuteNonQueryAsync() as of the below code.

```
 private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                //connection.Open(); //line commented
                 **await connection.OpenAsync();**
                Console.WriteLine("MySQL connected.");
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {

             }   





public void Insert()
            {
                    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
                    {
                          using(var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Admin\source\Bargstedt.csv"))
                    {
                    //List<string> listA = new List<string>();


                        while (!reader.EndOfStream)

                        {
                        ***await reader.OpenAsync();***

                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                            var values = line.Split(',');
                            string querynew = "INSERT INTO jobs"
                                      + "(nJobNumber,strClientReference,datPromisedDelivery)" 
                                      + "VALUES (@jobNo, @strClientName, @strClientReference)";


                        var cmd = new MySqlCommand();

                        cmd.CommandText= querynew;




                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("strClientName", "MySqlDbType.VarChar").Value =(values[1]);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("strClientReference", "MySqlDbType.VarChar").Value = values[2];



                    ***await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();***
                        // cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(); //Line commented

                    }
                    }
                    this.CloseConnection();
                }



        }
```

Before implemented this, I reckoned the issue was with the execution line since any of the data isn't written back to the database.

That is the reason it persuades me to include **await** open and execute lines to the source code likewise given in this [example](https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/tutorials/basic-api/).

Unfortunately, in all the places I have used **await** keyword (Highlighted in the above code) is triggering an error:

> Error CS4032  The 'await' operator can only be used within an async
>   method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and
>   changing its return type to 'Task'.

How to fix this issue and what do you think the reason which the database is not updating?

would it be fixed if this **'await'** method implemented correctly?

Comment: Might find it useful to read something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous code is more complicated. I would recommend that you stick with the (fully supported) synchronous methods until you get your database code working. So change `await connection.OpenAsync();` back to `connection.Open();`, `await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();` to `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, etc.

(Don't call an `Async` method without using an `await` statement, because it will keep executing in the background while your primary method keeps running, which may cause the same connection to be used simultaneously on two separate threads, causing an error.)

The example code you gave doesn't add a parameter value for `@jobNo`. That will cause an exception because the parameter isn't defined.

The code `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("strClientName", "MySqlDbType.VarChar").Value =(values[1])` is incorrectly adding a parameter with the literal string value `"MySqlDbType.VarChar"`, then overwriting it. It would be more straightforward to write `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("strClientName", values[1]);`.

Once you get your database code working, and want to switch to async, you can use `await` within the method body, then redeclare the method signature with the `async` keyword, e.g., `private async Task<bool> OpenConnection()`.

Comment: I have changed the  3 AddWithValue() statements as you've mentioned. But still, database is not updating @Bradley Grainger

Comment: @simon Can you update your question with your latest code?

Comment: @Simon The first thing I saw in that code was `conn.OpenAsync();`. As I wrote in my answer, _you must not do this_. Read up on async/await https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/ and always `await` the `Async` methods, or (my recommendation) just call the synchronous method instead.

Comment: Hey Bradley, It's weird that when I try to run the program using F11 (step Into) it actually works. Database updated successfully. But when I tried to Full run using F5 there will be the above exception. There is a timing issue I reckon. Any suggestions? @Bradley Grainger

Comment: That error message indicates that the binary protocol data received on the wire isn't what was expected. I don't know how an SSH tunnel handles multiple simultaneous connections; it seems possible that multiple data streams could be getting mixed up? A packet capture (of packets between your application and the local end of the SSH tunnel) might shed light on the issue.

Comment: Do you mind having a glance at this question? @Bradley Grainger https://stackoverflow.com/q/52489221/9589180