# How to fix error {"Expected to read 4 header bytes but only received 0."} in c#?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect to Google cloud MySQL.
    I get this error after `connection.open();`

> {"Expected to read 4 header bytes but only received 0."}

My code is:

```cs
  static void Main()
  {
    var csb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
    {
      Server = "35.228.221.113",
      UserID = "root",
      Password = "root",
      Database = "mysql",
      SslMode = MySqlSslMode.None
    };
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString))
    {
      connection.Open();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Googling for `mysql {"Expected to read 4 header bytes but only received 0."}` returns many links. Please update your question with which of those links you have read, and which suggestions you have already tried, so we don't waste your time sharing stuff you have already done.

Comment: i tried this links:
https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/540
https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/571
i also tried this code before in another pc and another database but the code was good.

Comment: What are these set to for you? https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/540#issuecomment-410412858

Comment: i dont have all this configs. i only tried run the code that was fine before... what could it be?

Comment: It looks like from searching web the TCP connection closed possibly due to a timeout or authentication issue.  The default timeout in the connection string is 15 seconds.  How long does it take before you get an error?

Comment: few seconds. but not 15.

Comment: You need to alter your config to extend the timeout. We've given you links about it to read and apply. Have you tried to do it?